# how to obtain contact list in qt

Tags: qt

i use this code and getting contact details of only one person ....

```
contactManager = new QContactManager();
QList<QContact> contacts = contactManager->contacts();
contacts.detail(QContactPhoneNumber::DefinitionName).value(QContactPhoneNumber::FieldNumber);

QContact a = contactManager->contact(contacts.count());
QContactPhoneNumber no = a.detail<QContactPhoneNumber>();
qDebug() << "Name:" << a.displayLabel() << "Number:" << " " << no.number() ;
UserId = a.displayLabel();
PhoneNumber = no.number();
```

output:

```
Name: andrew Number: +7811341255
```

but i want list of contact like this

```
Name: andrew Number: +7811341255
Name: person2 Number: +44124156
Name: person3 Number: +212113
```

....list of no of contact in phone
any help appreciated....

Comment: I can't really tell what you want and how that differs from what you already have. Could you clarify that a bit?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all of them, you should iterate over the `QList` returned by `QContactManager::contacts()`.

This should get you started (I'll just whip it up for you):

```
// Contacts contains a list of ID:s
QList<QContactLocalId> contacts = contactManager->contacts();

// Now iterate
QList<QContactLocalId>::iterator it;
for (it = contacts.begin(); it != contacts.end(); ++it)
{
  QContact contact = contactManager->contact(*it);
  // And print contact information...
  UserId name = contact.displayLabel();
  PhoneNumber number = contact.number();
  qDebug() << "Name: " << name
           << " Number: " << number << " ";
}
```

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.0-tp/qcontactmanager.html#contacts

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qlist.html

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qlist-iterator.html

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/iterators

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use `foreach(const QContact contact, contacts){...}`?

Answer (score 1):

Helped me alot...... Thanks...... :)

just a modification it's:

```
QList<QContactLocalId> contacts = contactManager->contactsIds();
```

not

```
QList<QContactLocalId> contacts = contactManager->contacts();
```

Comment: this is just a small addition, not a comprehensive answer - thus it should be a comment under the accepted answer. The usual way to thank for an helpful answer is upvoting it (see [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34464/159753)).

Answer (score 0):

To get a contact list of iOS & Android, you can also use the V-Play SDK for this. There is method [nativeUtils.getContacts()](https://v-play.net/updates/release-2-13-0-free-rewarded-videos-native-ads-for-google-admob-qt#get-contact-list-ios-android) which works like this:

```
import VPlayApps 1.0

App {
  AppListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: nativeUtils.getContacts()

    delegate: SimpleRow {
      text: modelData.name
      detailText: modelData.phoneNumber
    }
  }
}
```