# How to obtain contact list in Qt 5.2.

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I want to do the same as this post: **"[how to obtain contact list in qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255377/how-to-obtain-contact-list-in-qt)"**, but using qt 5.2.  I can`t use qt-contacts because this version doesn't have it.

Comment: I guess it has been merged with some class, because qt doesn't eliminate anything...!

Comment: it's part of [Qt Mobility](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility/contacts/source/4b93f8897b760914cb272182dfe8180a92c67012:)

Comment: yes its for old qt version, but in qt 5.2 it doesn`t exist, version 5.2 already have qt mobility in it´s core but this lib doesn´t exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On android you need to use QAndroidJniObject to call java code and return contacts to c++, you can see example project on my github repo https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qmlcontactlist